# The JDBC driver currently does not support COPY operations

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-data

Trying to use Spring's database automatic data initialization described here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

However when I execute my Maven build I get an error "ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: The JDBC driver currently does not support COPY operations"

Bactrace:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/ehansen/src/wimg/zuul/target/classes/data-postgresql.sql]: COPY public.zuul_permissions (id, actions, offers, sites) FROM stdin; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: The JDBC driver currently does not support COPY operations.
    Where: COPY zuul_permissions, line 1
```

It appears that the JDBC PostgreSQL driver doesn't support the COPY operation?  How else am I supposed to accomplish this if not in the Maven build?

Comment: Can you show the code that executes the copy statement ?

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the data set being used to initialize the database.